# Locking selective code and data pages of a Linux process in RAM

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, linker-scripts

I have multi-threaded Linux application that have a running memory footprint of around 150MB, when I use mlockall to lock all of the process in the memory. This is done so that page faults can be avoided for some high priority threads that have low latency requirements. However there are only select execution flow/context which has such requirements and I am trying to lock code and data only for these flows so that I can reduce the locked memory footprint of the process. 
The idea is to collect all these functions in a separate text section and then lock the pages.
A blue print of the idea is as follows

```
//Define a marker for compiler for all code that needs to be locked:
#define __hard_rt_fn  __section(.locked.txt)

//mark the identified functions with the marker
Event* __hard_rt_fn GetEvent();

//Ask the loader/linker script to give the start and end address of the 
.locked ():
{
    __locked_start = .;
    *(.text);
    *(.rodata.*);
}
__locked_size = SIZEOF(.locked);
Export(__locked_start);
Export(__locked_size);

//In the main initialisation function, lock the section

extern long int __locked_start;
extern long int __locked_size;

Main()
{
 ……
 mlock(__locked_start,__locked_size);
 ……

}
```

This method is inspired by the approach that is taken on embedded system where a sections of code needs to be relocated in RAM while the remaining stays back in ROM. 
I have  the following queries
 1.Is this achievable with dynamic (gnu)linkers/loaders?
 2.How to specify locking of pages for shared libraries dynamically loaded.
 3.Is there a better way or a tool to lock only identified sections of code and data.

Comment: Since you're going to such extreme measures, you probably have profiling data justifying it. Doesn't that profiling data also show you which sections of the current code caused the slowdown?

Comment: Yes, I can identify the execution flow which needs to be locked for low latency and also the data it needs to accomplish it. The slowdown occurs from page-fault which we need to avoid, rather than accomplish through re-factoring of code.